# Is it possible to connect NodeMCU ESP8266 arduino chip control to a windows form application through wifi?

Tags: c#, module, arduino-esp8266, relay

My goal is to make a windows form application that could turn on or off a relay module that is connected to a NodeMCU board with ESP8266 wifi module, that is connected to the same network as my computer.

I managed to control it through USB using SerialPort library, but I have no idea if its even possible to control it through wifi. This is how my arduino code looks like:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

int Module1 = 0;
int Module2 = 2;
const char* ssid = "Android";
const char* password = "password";

void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(9600);
 pinMode(Module1,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(Module2,OUTPUT);
}
void loop()
{
 char data = Serial.read();
 switch (data){
   case '1' : digitalWrite(Module1,HIGH); ;break;
   case '2' : digitalWrite(Module2,HIGH); ;break;
   case '3' : digitalWrite(Module1,LOW); ;break;
   case '4' : digitalWrite(Module2,LOW); ;break;
   }
}
```

Any way I could do the same but the controls would work through wifi? As in if I would be able to control the relay with a windows form app without connecting the board to the PC? (another power source for example)

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: Yes.

More long-winded version: You need to either connect your ESP board to a web service like IFTTT (see https://ifttt.com/ ) or write a web service on it that can react to messages from the client (see https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp8266-web-server-with-arduino-ide/ ).